# Add subquery to Select from same table

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

And I need to add PRECIO_NETO_EUR field extracted from this subquery:

```
SELECT (ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON*EUR_RATE) - x - y - z - k as PRECIO_NETO_EUR
FROM
(
    SELECT ((ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON-X-Y-Z)* ISNULL(ACUCDTO3,0)/100) AS K, X, Y, Z, ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON, EUR_RATE, ACUCDTO1, ACUCDTO2, ACUCDTO3, ACUCDTOGEN
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ((ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON-X-Y)* ISNULL(ACUCDTO2,0)/100) AS Z, X, Y, ACUCDTO2, ACUCDTO3, ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON, EUR_RATE, ACUCDTO1, ACUCDTOGEN
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT ((ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON-X)*ISNULL(ACUCDTO1,0)/100) AS Y, X, ACUCDTO2, ACUCDTO3, ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON, EUR_RATE, ACUCDTO1, ACUCDTOGEN
            FROM
            (
                SELECT (ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON*EUR_RATE * ACUCDTOGEN / 100) AS X, ACUCDTO1, ACUCDTO2, ACUCDTO3, ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON, ACUCDTOGEN, EUR_RATE
                FROM TABLE
            ) CALCULOX
        ) CALCULOY
    ) CALCULOZ
) CALCULOFINAL
```

Both queries access the same **table** so I understand that it is not necessary to do an inner join. What would be the best way to do this task?

Comment: In my opinion, if you must do something like this, using `APPLY` to a `VALUES` table construct or a `CTE` are *far* more readable.

Comment: Yes, I would vote for CTEs here.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't know if this answers your question, it's unclear, but if I am correctly reading through the lines you could do this. This, however, is a direct "translation" of your query into using `VALUES` table constructs; which in my opinion makes it far more readable and doesn't need all those ugly nested sub queries:

```sql
SELECT (YT.ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON * YT.EUR_RATE) - X.X - Y.Y - Z.Z - K.K AS PRECIO_NETO_EUR,
       YT.ACUCDTO1,
       YT.ACUCDTO2,
       YT.ACUCDTO3,
       YT.ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON,
       YT.ACUCDTOGEN,
       YT.EUR_RATE
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (YT.ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON * YT.EUR_RATE * YT.ACUCDTOGEN / 100)) X (X)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES ((YT.ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON - X.X) * ISNULL(YT.ACUCDTO1, 0) / 100)) Y (Y)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES ((YT.ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON - X.X - Y.Y) * ISNULL(YT.ACUCDTO2, 0) / 100)) Z (Z)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES ((ACUCPRECIOBRUTOMON - X.X - Y.Y - Z.Z) * ISNULL(YT.ACUCDTO3, 0) / 100)) K (K);
```

Comment: I also use this the whole time, although with multiple values I use `SELECT` (without `FROM`) instead of `VALUES` I find it more readable